# Is there a way to have Ray.wait return as many finished items as possible?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, ray

I have a dynamic queue where I'm processing items using ray.wait(), at the moment, ray.wait is returning one item at a time as soon as it's done; however, a lot of the time, more than one item is finished at the same time (the number of items done at each iteration varies). Is there a way to get all the items that are finished? If it helps, in the items, I have a dict_key indicating whether they're done or not.

Here's a little exampe:

```
        tasks = [x for x in queue if not blocked(x)]
        queue = [x for x in queue if x not in tasks]
        running_temp  = [self.process.remote(node) for node in tasks]
        
        running_tasks  = running_tasks + running_temp
        #Here, finished tasks will always be a single item, and unfinished tasks will be all the other unfinished tasks, whether we're still waiting or they're completed, how can I make sure all the finished tasks are in the finished tasks list???

        finished_tasks, unfinished_tasks = ray.wait(running_tasks)
        running_tasks = unfinished_tasks
        
        out = ray.get(finished_tasks)
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, `ray.wait` takes an optional parameter, `num_returns` which waits until that many object refs finish (unless a timeout is specified and comes first).

In your case, you may want to do

```
ray.wait(running_tasks, num_returns=len(running_tasks))
```

If you want to wait for multiple tasks, but not all of them, you can also specify a timeout, and it will return as many tasks as possible in that amount of time.

```
# Return as many tasks as possible after giving them 30s to run.
finished, running = ray.wait(running_tasks, num_returns=len(running_tasks), timeout=30)
```